# a function with linear growth is $C^1$ and Lipschitz.

Tags: analysis

I would like to know how to proof that a function with linear growth (meaning $|f(x)| \le a|x|+b$) is $C^1$ and Lipschitz. 
Thanks.

Comment: Such a function (linear growth) need not be even ${\cal C}^1$.  Counterexample: [Triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave).  Are you sure the question is stated correctly?  Also, please follow the community guidelines for asking a question.  They include showing effort: what have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  What are you unsure about?  This forum is intended for learning, not obtaining a solutions manual.

Comment: ok moreover the statement is not true,so thanks anyway.

Comment: I agree with avs just take for $x\ge 0$ $\lfloor x\rfloor\le |x|$ and floor function is discontinuous. Even with alternate definition $f(x)/ax\to 1$ I think same kind of counterexample works.

Comment: of course ,same goes with the function min

Comment: the thing is i face great difficulties solving a question

Answer (score 2):

The function 
$$x \mapsto |x|$$

has linear growth (as you define it) but is not $\mathcal{C}^1$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational, $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational satisfies the hypothesis with $a=0$ and $b=1$. It is not continuous at any point!